# ArgumentError: no default `Tables.columns` implementation for type: XLSX.XLSXFile

Tags: julia, julia-dataframe

I have a very simple excel file (.xlsx) it contains just 2 columns and 2 rows with values.
But when I run the code below I get `` ArgumentError: no default `Tables.columns` implementation for type: XLSX.XLSXFile ``, for both `readxlsx` and `openxlsx` Why is that? Is it something with DataFrames or with XLXS pkg?

The excel file looks like this [image]

```
|  text  | text  |
------------------
|   0    |   1   |
------------------

using DataFrames
using XLSX

df = XLSX.readxlsx("Test1.xlsx")
```

As a suggested solution I'm running the following code
The excel file looks like this

```
|  text  | text  |
------------------
|   0    |   1   |
------------------

using DataFrames
using XLSX

df = DataFrame(XLSX.readtable("Test1.xlsx", "Blad1"))
```

but that gives the following error `` ArgumentError: 'Tuple{Vector{Any}, Vector{Symbol}}' iterates 'Vector{Any}' values, which doesn't satisfy the Tables.jl `AbstractRow` interface ``

Comment: -1 for now. The error can't be replicated with the given information. In its current state, I don't think this question will be helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

[The tutorial](https://felipenoris.github.io/XLSX.jl/stable/tutorial/#Read-Tabular-Data) includes a relevant example with  `readtable`:

```
julia> using DataFrames, XLSX

julia> df = DataFrame(XLSX.readtable("myfile.xlsx", "mysheet"))
3×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ HeaderA │ HeaderB  │
├─────┼─────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 1       │ "first"  │
│ 2   │ 2       │ "second" │
│ 3   │ 3       │ "third"  │
```

I've tried to replicate your setup as closely as possible with the information you've given. However, I can't replicate your error with `readtable`:

```
$ julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.8.1 (2022-09-06)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

(@v1.8) pkg> activate --temp
  Activating new project

julia> using DataFrames, XLSX

julia> df = DataFrame(XLSX.readtable("Test1.xlsx", "Blad1"))
1×2 DataFrame
 Row │ Zero  One
     │ Any   Any
─────┼───────────
   1 │ 0     1
```

This makes me suspect that the problem is elsewhere. Could you please try running everything in a temporary project, as I've done here? I want to be sure that another package is not interfering.

Comment: I tried that also, but that gives me ```ArgumentError: 'Tuple{Vector{Any}, Vector{Symbol}}' iterates 'Vector{Any}' values, which doesn't satisfy the Tables.jl `AbstractRow` interface```

Comment: Have updated the question with an image of the excel file and the code I'm running.

Comment: As I wrote before, if I use readtable ```df = DataFrame(XLSX.readtable("Test1.xlsx", "Blad1"))``` I get the following error ```ArgumentError: 'Tuple{Vector{Any}, Vector{Symbol}}' iterates 'Vector{Any}' values, which doesn't satisfy the Tables.jl `AbstractRow` interface```

Comment: I cannot replicate your error, so I suspect the problem is elsewhere. Could you please try running the code in a new project environment, as I've done above? Also, what versions of Julia and each package are you using? What is the output of `versioninfo()`?